# In the Python interpreter, how do you return a value without single quotes around it?

Tags: python, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

In the Python interpreter, how do you return a value without single quotes around it?

Example:

```py
>>> def function(x):
...     return x
...
>>> function("hi")
'hi'
```

I expect it to return `hi` instead of `'hi'`

Answer (score 48, accepted):

In the Python interactive prompt, if you return a string, it will be *displayed* with quotes around it, mainly so that you know it's a string.

If you just *print* the string, it will not be shown with quotes (unless the string *has* quotes in it).

```
>>> 1 # just a number, so no quotes
1
>>> "hi" # just a string, displayed with quotes
'hi'
>>> print("hi") # being *printed* to the screen, so do not show quotes
hi
>>> "'hello'" # string with embedded single quotes
"'hello'"
>>> print("'hello'") # *printing* a string with embedded single quotes
'hello'
```

If you actually *do* need to *remove* leading/trailing quotation marks, use the `.strip` method of the string to remove single and/or double quotes:

```
>>> print("""'"hello"'""")
'"hello"'
>>> print("""'"hello"'""".strip('"\''))
hello
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way that will remove all the single quotes in a string.

```
def remove(x):
    return x.replace("'", "")
```

Here's another alternative that will remove the first and last character.

```
def remove2(x):
    return x[1:-1]
```