# Remove b while printing binary values in Python

Tags: python, printing, binary

I'm making my first python script that opens a file as binary, reads some bytes and based on their values, does something. All of that is working fine.
Main issue is want to print 2 bytes, but need to escape the b' char that appears on the screen so I can have only the hex value there. I'm printing like this and this is the results:

`print(content)` -> `b'\xdf\x12`

`print(binascii.hexlify(content))` -> `b'df12'`

My goal is print to screen just DF12 which are the 2 bytes I need.

I've searched and tried some different options but none worked. I'm using Python 34.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python return without " ' "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482649/python-return-without)

Comment: I'd rather use [`base64.b16encode`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/base64.html#base64.b16encode) than `hexlify` for this. It will directly give you a string which you can print.

Answer (score 0):

**Python 3.***:

```
s = b'\xdf\x12'
("{:02X}"*len(s)).format(*s)
```

Or as suggested @swenzel:

```
from base64 import b16encode
s = b'\xdf\x12'
b16encode(s).decode('utf-8')
```

**Python 2.7.***

```
s = b'\xdf\x12'
s.encode('hex')
```

Or:

```
from base64 import b16encode
s = b'\xdf\x12'
b16encode(s)
```

Comment: Also usefull lib for parsing binary: http://williballenthin.com/blog/2015/09/08/parsing-binary-data-with-%60vstruct%60/