# Python: How to remove quotes when I add csv data to the list and print it

Tags: python, csv

I am facing a little problem here when I open csv file.
I get the CSV data and put it in the list.
Once I print the list it populates the data I need + I get the following empty brackets: `['', '', '']`:

```
[['1', '2', 'white'], ['2', '4', 'black'], ['2', '5', 'black'], 
 ['2', '5', 'black'], ['1', '4', 'white'], ['', '', ''], ['', '', ''] etc..
```

How to get rid of the additional `['', '', '']` part?

Here is my code, sorry I am quite new to this and I could not find the answer on the web:

```
import math
import csv


class CylinderFactory:

    def __init__(self,filename):

        self.filename = filename
        self.mylist=[]
        self.height = []
        self.diameter=[]

        with open(self.filename, "r") as f:
            reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")
            for row in reader:
                self.mylist.append(row)
                self.height.append(row[0])
                self.diameter.append(row[1])

def main():

   new=CylinderFactory("testfile.csv")
   print(new.mylist)
   print(new.height)

main()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python interpreter, return without " ' "](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482649/in-python-interpreter-return-without)

Comment: open `testfile.csv` in normal editor and remove empty lines ;) and next time don't save empty lines when you create CSV.

Comment: post the testfile.csv

Comment: normally use `if` to check values in `row` before you append to `self.mylist` and `self.height`

Answer (score 2):

You can just avoid processing such lines, e.g.

```
for row in reader:
    if row == ['', '', '']:
        continue
    self.mylist.append(row)
    ...
```

A nice more general condition would be:

```
    if not any(row):
```

or if you want to avoid rows that have *any* empty values, e.g. `[['1', '2', '']`:

```
    if not all(row):
```