# print function output

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Python 3:

```
>>> str="Hello" # declare a string str
>>> print(str)
Hello
>>> str
'Hello'
```

When I don't use `print` to print the string and simply write `>>> str` then the output comes in single quotes and when I use `>>> print(str)` the output does not come in single quotes. So why does this happen?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Python interpreter, return without " ' "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482649/in-python-interpreter-return-without)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python interactive shell:
If you declare a variable, then when you type the name of that variable, Python interactive shell will return the value of it. Because there are many data types, if you declare a string, and then call it, Python interactive shell will display it with quotes around, so that you can know it is a string

```
>>> str = "Hello"
>>> str
'Hello'
```

If you use the `print()` function to print the string out, then the string is being "printed". No quotes. Nothing more, nothing less.

Answer (score 0):

When you simply write >>>str you are calling that variable, so the single quotes help to denote that it is a string, but using the print() function it prints the contents of str to the IDLE. Hope this helps :)