# How to remove the quotes around the value in the string representation of a dict?

Tags: python, dictionary, repr

How can I not print the quotes around a string? I understand that this is a string, as a result Python is adding the quotes.

To give more context:

```py
def a(content):
    return {'row_contents': content}

print(a("Hello"))
```

This gives output as:

> ```
> {'row_contents': 'Hello'}
> ```

I want to remove the quotes around *Hello* while returning this (something as below)

> ```
> {'row_contents': Hello}
> ```

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: Of course, this is possible. But can you explain a little bit more what you're trying to do? Are you sure this isn't an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem)?

Comment: Already an answer is there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482649/in-python-interpreter-return-without

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Python interpreter, return without " ' "](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482649/in-python-interpreter-return-without)

Comment: @ManasKhandelwal: It doesn't. I do not want to use print as that will not return the value i am expecting as output which could be used in another variable

Comment: @finefoot I want to return a `dict`

Comment: @PrabhatRatnala Did you make it work?

Answer (score 1):

you can ues `f string`

```
def a(content):
    return f"{{'row_contents': {content}}}"


print(a("Hello"))
```

or just this:

```
def a(content):
    return "{'row_contents':"+content+"}"
```

Output:

```
{'row_contents': Hello}
```

Answer (score 1):

I still believe this question has a high probability of being an [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem).

However, regarding your question as it stands: If you don't want to modify `print`, you're only left with modifying the return value of your function `a`. Your comment above says:

> I want to return a `dict`

This sounds like simply returning a modified string representation of `{'row_contents': content}` isn't really what you're looking for. Yet, `dict.__repr__` itself is read-only, so I guess the closest solution would be to return an instance of a custom `dict` subclass:

```py
class CustomDict(dict):
    def __repr__(self):
        return "{" + ", ".join([repr(k) + ": " + str(v) for k, v in self.items()]) + "}"

def a(content):
    return CustomDict({'row_contents': content})

print(a("Hello"))
print(isinstance(a("Hello"), dict))
```

Which prints:

```
{'row_contents': Hello}
True
```

You might need to improve `CustomDict.__repr__` depending on what modifications are necessary to provide the desired output. You could also modify the original string representation `super().__repr__()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply get the string representation of the dictionary and remove the single quotes.

```
def a(content):
    return {'row_contents': content}

def print_dict_without_quotes(d):
    print(str(d).replace("'", "").replace('"', ''))

print_dict_without_quotes(a("Hello"))
```

Output:

```
{row_contents: Hello}
```

Comment: Yet, this removes the quotes from the keys, too.